# subtract value each time we persist a new record

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I want to subtract a value from another field each time I add a new record 
this is my case:example

```
soldeJours(from entity contrat) = nbjours (from entity contrat) - dureeAssistance (from entity assistance)
```

for example

> nbjours = 20 and when I add a new assistance dureeassistance =5
>    soldeJours = 15 when add another assistance durée assistance =3
>    soldeJours = 12

Each time I add a new record in assistance soldejours automatically decrements and persisted into db and showed in the interface.

Ps: I have a one-to-many relation between contract and assistance (a contract can have more than one assistance)

here's my entity Contrat

```
package model.entitie;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Contrat.findAll", query = "select o from Contrat o") })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Contrat_Id_Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "CONTRAT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 50)
public class Contrat implements Serializable {
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String annee;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String client;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Contrat_Id_Seq_Gen")
    @Column(name = "ID_CONTRAT", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    private String idContrat;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String information;
    @Column(name = "NB_JOURS")
    public BigDecimal nbJours;
    @Column(name = "SOLDE_JOURS")
    public BigDecimal soldeJours;
    @Column (name="ETATCON")
    private String etatCon;

    public void setEtatCon(String etatCon) {
        this.etatCon = etatCon;
    }

    public String getEtatCon() {
        return etatCon;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrat" ,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Assistance> assistanceList;

    public Contrat() {
    }

    public Contrat(String annee, String client, String idContrat, String information, BigDecimal nbJours,
                   BigDecimal soldeJours, String etatCon) {
        this.annee = annee;
        this.client = client;
        this.idContrat = idContrat;
        this.information = information;
        this.nbJours = nbJours;
        this.soldeJours = soldeJours;
        this.etatCon = etatCon;
    }

    public String getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(String annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getIdContrat() {
        return idContrat;
    }

    public void setIdContrat(String idContrat) {
        this.idContrat = idContrat;
    }

    public String getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(String information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    public BigDecimal getNbJours() {
        return nbJours;
        }

    public void setNbJours(BigDecimal nbJours) {
        this.nbJours = nbJours;
    }

   /*public void setSoldeJours(BigDecimal soldeJours) {
        this.soldeJours = soldeJours.subtract(nbJours);
    }*/

    public BigDecimal getSoldeJours() {
        return soldeJours;
    }

    public void setSoldeJours(BigDecimal soldeJours, Assistance assistance) {
        this.soldeJours = nbJours.subtract(assistance.getDureeAssistance());
    }

    public List<Assistance> getAssistanceList() {
        return assistanceList;
    }

    public void setAssistanceList(List<Assistance> assistanceList) {
        this.assistanceList = assistanceList;
    }

    public Assistance addAssistance(Assistance assistance) {
        getAssistanceList().add(assistance);
        assistance.setContrat(this);
        return assistance;
    }

    public Assistance removeAssistance(Assistance assistance) {
        getAssistanceList().remove(assistance);
        assistance.setContrat(null);
        return assistance;
    }
}
```

and here my entity Assistance

```
package model.entitie;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Assistance.findAll", query = "select o from Assistance o") })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Assistance_Id_Seq_Gen", sequenceName = "ASSISTANCE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1,
                   initialValue = 50)
public class Assistance implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7916354262572083045L;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String client;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    private Date dateCreation;
    @Column(name = "DUREE_ASSISTANCE")
    private BigDecimal dureeAssistance;
    @Column(name = "ETAT_ASSISTANCE", length = 4000)
    private String etatAssistance;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ASSISTANCE", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Assistance_Id_Seq_Gen")
    private String idAssistance;
    @Column(name = "ING_AFF", length = 4000)
    private String ingAff;
    @Column(name = "OUVERT_PAR", length = 4000)
    private String ouvertPar;
    @Column(name = "SUJET_ASS", length = 4000)
    private String sujetAss;
    @Column(name = "ETATASS", length = 4000)
    private String etatAss;

    public void setEtatAss(String etatAss) {
        this.etatAss = etatAss;
    }

    public String getEtatAss() {
        return etatAss;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRAT_ID", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Contrat contrat;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assistance", cascade =CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Intervention> interventionList;

    public Assistance() {
    }

    public Assistance(Contrat contrat, Date dateCreation, BigDecimal dureeAssistance, String etatAssistance,
                      String idAssistance, String ingAff, String ouvertPar, String sujetAss, String client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.contrat = contrat;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.dureeAssistance = dureeAssistance;
        this.etatAssistance = etatAssistance;
        this.idAssistance = idAssistance;
        this.ingAff = ingAff;
        this.ouvertPar = ouvertPar;
        this.sujetAss = sujetAss;
        this.etatAssistance = etatAssistance;

        this.contrat.soldeJours = this.contrat.soldeJours.subtract(this.dureeAssistance);
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }


    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDureeAssistance() {
        return dureeAssistance;
    }

    public void setDureeAssistance(BigDecimal dureeAssistance) {
        // this.contrat.nbJours = this.contrat.soldeJours.subtract(dureeAssistance);
        this.dureeAssistance = dureeAssistance;
    }

    public String getEtatAssistance() {
        return etatAssistance;
    }

    public void setEtatAssistance(String etatAssistance) {
        this.etatAssistance = etatAssistance;
    }

    public String getIdAssistance() {
        return idAssistance;
    }

    public void setIdAssistance(String idAssistance) {
        this.idAssistance = idAssistance;
    }

    public String getIngAff() {
        return ingAff;
    }

    public void setIngAff(String ingAff) {
        this.ingAff = ingAff;
    }

    public String getOuvertPar() {
        return ouvertPar;
    }

    public void setOuvertPar(String ouvertPar) {
        this.ouvertPar = ouvertPar;
    }

    public String getSujetAss() {
        return sujetAss;
    }

    public void setSujetAss(String sujetAss) {
        this.sujetAss = sujetAss;
    }

    public Contrat getContrat() {
        return contrat;
    }

    public void setContrat(Contrat contrat) {
        this.contrat = contrat;
    }

    public List<Intervention> getInterventionList() {
        return interventionList;
    }

    public void setInterventionList(List<Intervention> interventionList) {
        this.interventionList = interventionList;
    }
    public Intervention addIntervention (Intervention intervention)
    {
        getInterventionList().add(intervention);
        intervention.setAssistance(this);
        return intervention;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to do that in the entity itself ? can't you simply use a repository or dao and put that simple substraction logic in it ?

Comment: yes just in entity or in the session bean because i have a project's hierarchy that i have to respect

Comment: session bean yea ... you  do all the logic in it and use entity just to persist into DB ... that's it, and then, what is your question ?

Comment: I want to substract a value from another field each time i add a new record this is my case:example soldeJours(from entity contrat) = nbjours (from entity contrat) - dureeAssistance (from entity assistance)

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal nbJours = contrat.getNbJours();
for (Assistance assistance : contrat.getAssistanceList()) {
  nbJours = nbJours.substract(assistance.getDureeAssistance());
}
contrat.setSoldeJours(nbJours);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: actually there is no problem at all ! this is just a simple subtraction logic ...

Comment: it work's fine when i merge a contrat but when i want to list all contrat and merge them automaticly i got a **java.lang.NullPointerException** in (BigDecimal nbJours = contrat.getNbJours();) 

here my listallfunction
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<Contrat> getContratFindAll() {
    mergeContrat(contrat);
    return em.createNamedQuery("Contrat.findAll", Contrat.class).getResultList();
    }

Comment: are you sure that your query works ? and that you get all the "contrat" ? ... try debugging a bit, and let me know what is null

Comment: Oui bien sur la requete marcha comme il faut, et je peux lister tout les contrat mais une fois que je veux faire le calcule du solde jours restant avant d'afficher la liste des contrat il m'affiche un NullPointerException  au niveau de (BigDecimal nbJours = contrat.getNbJours(); puisque j'ai fait le traitement au niveau de la fonction mergeContrat() et je l'appel au sein de la fonction LISTALL

Comment: Tu n'aura jamais de réponse mon ami ... tu ne cherches pas assez ... tu espères qu'on fasse ton boulot là ... regardes ta requêtes sql .. debug .. et corriges la ... je n'ai pas d'autres cobseils à te donner